# how to get the value of the last inserted primary key id

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table storing details of all customers. The `customer_id` is the primary key of `customer table`. I need to get the value of the recently inserted customer's customer_id.How can I get it? Please help me.What is the syntax for it?

Comment: You can use transaction.If you are using PHP/MYSQL then see here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php.

Comment: What language do you use (add mention of it to question)?

Comment: show the data you have and what you want to end up in the database

Answer (score 1):

You can try out following approaches:

1.You can create a database object **SEQUENCE**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE <seqname> [ INCREMENT increment ]
[ MINVALUE minvalue ] [ MAXVALUE maxvalue ]
[ START start ] [ CACHE cache ] [ CYCLE ]
```

Then while inserting record in Parent table in your case it is customer Table use

> seqname.nextval  for customer_id field.

and to insert the same record in the order table

> seqname.currval for order_id

2.You can also use transcation also.The details you can find on this [[link]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert values for customer_id, order_id into order table while inserting into customer table. I believe order_id is incremental field. Later on when you will get order info you can update order table for that customer_id and order_id.

Comment: thank you Hpatel..But I didn't follow you.Can you explain it in detail??